# Running nginx container as non-root from nginx-alpine image

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, devops

I am trying to run container from nginx-alpine as a non root user and getting the below error.

**[emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)**

Question: Do I need to add different port inside the dockerfile for the non-root user along with USER instruction?

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct intuition.

Ports in the range `1-1024` need privileged permission to be bound. As you are starting nginx as a non-root user, you cannot bind nginx to listen on port 80.

Only way to fix this is to make Nginx listen on a non-privilege port >1024. To do this, you will need to feed a custom nginx.conf file. This should solve your immediate problem.

But there will be other permission issues down the line as nginx starts trying to access `/var/log` to write logs, `/var/tmp/` for temp files etc.

The best option is to use the non-root nginx docker image itself. https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged

Comment: You can use CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE to bind, but I would research and understand this, maybe not the option to use, but for you to learn this option. If you want to use this option. More information at the following webpage, https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html

Answer (score -1):

From the following article,
https://medium.com/@callback.insanity/forwarding-nginx-logs-to-docker-3bb6283a207

1. The user `nobody` which is a non root user, does not have access to the `tty` group so it can write to `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr`.
2. In order for Docker logs to capture output from Nginx, you have to tell Nginx to write to `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr`.

In my nginx.conf I have:

```
# nginx.conf
error_log  stderr warn;
access_log  /dev/stdout main;
```

3. The final step is to ensure that `/proc/self/fd/0,1,2` file descriptors are accessible by the Docker container, regardless if using vanilla Docker or Docker Compose.
   For example, `/dev/stdout` points to file `descriptor/proc/self/fd/1` , which in turn points to device `/dev/pts/0` or similar.
   If you don’t tell Docker to allocate the pts device using the tty flag in Docker Compose or `-t` in Docker, then writing to `/dev/stdout` when running the container as non-root fails.

Comment: This answer is completely off-track the original question. The OP asked about the specific error preventing him from starting the container. There was no mention of logs

Comment: I guess my answer should of stated a permissions problem would arise, when this problem has been resolved. Your third paragraph has even stated this in your answer.

Comment: Even if the OP would have give tty access to his user, would it solve the bind() error he was facing? If so, I withdraw my comment.

Comment: I have already stated in my last comment "I guess my answer should have stated a permissions problem" and I probably should of made a comment instead.

Comment: I am running nginx from non-root unprivileged user -https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged. but i can see the container logs got struck

Comment: Container logs:    [root@docker alpine]# docker logs fffa4ecf404c   
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Comment: last three lines of the logs: 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up

Comment: Any help in that how can I make my container logs rolling

Comment: due to their slimness I am using nginx alpine image 1.19.6